# Strange behavior in Java, is it just me?

Tags: java, behavior

I have the following lines :

```
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++) System.out.print("\nA : "+i);
//    System.out.println("");
//    for (int i=0;i<3;i++) System.out.println("B : "+i);
```

The output is :

```
A : 0
A : 1
A : 2A : 2
```

Why ? I expected this :

```
A : 0
A : 1
A : 2
```

But if I uncomment the 2nd and 3rd lines [ together or one at a time ], it behaved correctly ? What's going on ? Is it my PC problem, or my NB6.7 problem ? I can't believe Java would do this !

Edit :

```
 for (int i=0;i<3;i++) System.out.print("A: "+i+"\n")
```

works correctly as expected.

When I ran it from command line, no problem at all, seems like a NB problem.

Comment: Is that the entire code? Any chance there's a stray line elsewhere that's providing that last output?

Comment: At last a "doesn't work on my machine" syndrom:)

Comment: have you tried executing the same code on the command line? at least that would tell you if it is NB or your system at fault.

Comment: FWIW, I'm on NB 6.9 (on Linux w/ Java 1.6) and don't see this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        for (int i=0;i<3;i++) System.out.print("\nA : "+i);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Jon\Test>javac Test.java

C:\Users\Jon\Test>java Test

A : 0
A : 1
A : 2
C:\Users\Jon\Test>
```

Perhaps Netbeans is just echoing the last line of output when the app terminates?

Comment: I did think about a buffer flushing myself but don't know enough about Java to volunteer that.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me as well, but try the following and tell us what it does.
Try putting the newline after i.e. `print("A: "+i+"\n");`